# Finding usb drive paths in Mac OS 10.4

Tags: macos, usb-drive, system-profiler

The `system_profiler` command in Mac OS 10.5 shows the mounted volume paths for the associated USB drives. In 10.4, however, they are not shown. Any ideas on how I can get the mount location for USB drives in 10.4?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disk Utility can show you:

```
diskutil list # to get the device/sector numbers
diskutil info /dev/diskXsY
```

These will likely end up mounting in /Volumes/.

Comment: `/Volumes/` I will be coming back to this one in the future... I know for sure... Thanks!